# How to calculate a mean based on values different and equal from 0

Tags: r

Please be aware that for the first ID = A, there are two rows containing information, while the remaining rows have a value of 0. I am interested in obtaining the count of values that are different from 0.

```
ID  Released
A   2
A   2
A   0
A   0
B   20
B   15
B   9
B   0
```

Output

```
ID  n  RateReleased
A   4    50% 
B   4    75%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
f <- scales::percent_format()
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(), 
    RateReleased = mean(Released != 0) %>% f()
  )
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 × 3
>   ID        n RateReleased
>   <chr> <int> <chr>       
> 1 A         4 50%         
> 2 B         4 75%
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(Released ~ ID, dat, \(x) c(n=length(x), rate=sprintf('%s%%', mean(x != 0)*100)))
#   ID Released.n Released.rate
# 1  A          4           50%
# 2  B          4           75%
```

Or

```
aggregate(Released ~ ID, dat, \(x) c(n=length(x), rate=mean(x != 0)))
#   ID Released.n Released.rate
# 1  A       4.00          0.50
# 2  B       4.00          0.75
```

Or maybe

```
with(dat, xtabs(Released > 0 ~ ID) / tapply(Released, ID, length))
# ID
#    A    B 
# 0.50 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I can think of would be to work with all non-zero values as if they were ones. Something like:

```
tapply(df$Released>0, df$ID, FUN=mean)
```